# API for text analysis or text extraction or semantic analysis (i.e., dates, titles, locations)?

Tags: web-services, api, full-text-search, semantics

Are there any APIs available which could help us do the following:

Given a body of text, extract:

1) The name of a restaurant

2) The date it was opened

3) A description of the restaurant

4) The restaurant owner

Assume the body of text contains all this information in unstructured format.

Obviously, we could rely on Amazon mTurk. But we're curious if an API allows something to be done programmatically -- or if not extract all these elements, at least extract some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone just sent me this on Quora: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-text-analytics-API-+-service.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The API's for this issue can be flexible or not with the content and the capacity to create results, and in relation with this flexibility there are companies that are offering very good API's to implement directly.

One of the best known API's in this field is [here](https://www.bitext.com/sentiment-analysis/)

The company is also recognized by Radian6 link [here](http://www.radian6.com/what-we-sell/marketingcloud/analysis-insights/features/bitext/)